# Docker, djnango, postgress переменные окружения

Tags: docker, .env

Ни как не могу понять как и где указать переменные окружения... Как известно приватные данные нужно записывать в переменные окружения, но вот у меня возник вопрос:

Имеется: Docker, docker-compose, django и postgress. Вопрос такой, куда правильно записывать переменные окружения? В Dockerfile? В docker-compose.yml? или .env? Очень хочется организовать единую точку управления, что бы не получилось что часть данных в одном месте, часть в другом и т.д.

Я предполагаю что логично было бы записать все в .env файл и если так то могу ли я выбирать конкретные переменные в конкретные параметры docker-compose? Например так:

**.ENV**

```
POSTGRES_USER='user'
POSTGRES_PASSWORD='passwrod'
POSTGRES_DB='django_db'
```

А в docer-compose указать их как-то так:

**COMPOSE**

```
postgres:
  container_name: postgres
  image: postgres
  expose:
    - 5423
  environment:
    - POSTGRES_USER=(env.POSTGRESS_USER)
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=(env.POSTGRESS_PASSWORD)
    - POSTGRES_DB=(env.POSTGRESS_DB)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для тех кто тоже затупил....

1. Все секретные переменные хранятся в файле .env;
2. Делаем копию файла и переименовываем его в .env_template;
3. Файл .env добавляем в .gitignore;
4. В файле .env_template оставляем все переменные, но удаляем их значения...

**ПРИМЕР**

**.env**

```
Django config
SECRET_KEY=secret_key
DEBUG=True
DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS=*

Database config
DB_ENGINE=django.db.backends.postgresql
POSTGRES_DB=postgres
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres_pass
POSTGRES_USER=postgres_user
POSTGRES_NAME=postgres
POSTGRES_HOST=localhost
POSTGRES_PORT=5432
```

**.env_tamplate**

```
Django config
SECRET_KEY=
DEBUG=
DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS=
    
Database config
DB_ENGINE=
POSTGRES_DB=
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=
POSTGRES_USER=
POSTGRES_NAME=
POSTGRES_HOST=
POSTGRES_PORT=
```

Каждый сотрудник скачивает себе .env_template и заполняет переменные своими данными